# Return the correct url of static file in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

model.py:

```
class Album(models.Model):{
    poster = models.ImageField upload_to='static/images/album/%Y/%m/%d')
}
```

serializer.py

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
doc = DoctorSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = Album
    fields = '__all__'
```

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[ 
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
```

views.py

```
class index(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer    
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
```

When I upload the image under http://127.0.0.1:8008/admin/qa/album/, the image show as 'static/images/album/2018/06/27/xxxxxx.jpg' at the poster field in the database. And I can access to the image through http://127.0.0.1:8008/static/images/album/2018/06/27/xxxxxx.jpg.

However, in the index view, the Django Rest Framework API return the url of the image as:
http://127.0.0.1:8008/api/index/static/images/album/2018/06/27/xxxxxx.jpg, which make the image 404.

Why the /api/index/ has been added to the url? What's wrong with my setting? Need your help...

Comment: Can you show related view and serializer?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner added

Comment: It's a better idea to adhere to the conventions. Conventionally, uploaded files are stored in a directory called `media`. And the related settings are `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`. Whereas, the `static` directory should hold your site's static assets, like logo, css, javascript, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To propely serve media files you need to add [`MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#media-url) and [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#media-roo) to your settings also:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

Note if you set `static` directory with `MEDIA_ROOT` setting in `upload_to` path you can skip `static`:

```
poster = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/album/%Y/%m/%d')
```

In `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    # your urls here
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**UPD**

As @brunodesthuilliers said in comment, you'd better divide media and static files and use `media` url and directory instead of `static`:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'medial')
```

Comment: "/static/" being canonically used for staticfiles, it would be better to use something else for medias... NB : staticfiles => site assets (css, images etc) that are part of the projects source code, medias=> files uploaded by users, not part of the project's source code.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you for clarification.

Comment: I followed your code, and the image can be accessed correctly. However, the url looks wried: http://127.0.0.1:8008/media/media/images/album/2018/06/27/h02.jpg. Why there are two /media/? Anything wrong?

Comment: @mrhaoji did you remove media from uploaded_to value in model?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner sure! right the model.py shown as: poster = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/album/%Y/%m/%d')

Comment: @mrhaoji hm.. Try to reupload file.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner ok, it works now after I restart the server...thx a lot!